# updateSearchIndexConfig.php

Tags: elasticsearch, heroku, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I'm installing CirrusSearch extension in this environment:

```
MediaWiki   1.34.2
PHP 7.3.22 (cgi-fcgi)
MySQL   5.6.41-84.1
ICU 4.2.1
Lua 5.1.5
```

I'm also using the Heroku's Searchbox add-on with Elasticsearch 6.8.8.

When I try to build the index, i get the following error:

```
Elastica\Exception\Connection\HttpException from line 189 .. Elastica/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Transport/Http.php: Couldn't connect to host, Elasticsearch down?
```

Does anyone knows what's happening? Can you guys help me?

Comment: Is Elasticsearch up?

Comment: Here, the log: 2020-09-20T20:26:07+00:00 {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"type_missing_exception","reason":"type[[null]] missing","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"_all"}],"type":"type_missing_exception","reason":"type[[null]] missing","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"_all"},"status":404}

Comment: I luckly managed to connect to the cluster by adding the port and scheme variables:

$wgCirrusSearchClusters = [
    'default' => [
        [ 
            'host'  => 'host.name.com',
            'port'  => 443,
            'scheme'=> 'https'
        ],
    ]
];
Now, I'm getting this error:

php updateSearchIndexConfig.php
indexing namespaces...
mw_cirrus_metastore missing, creating new metastore index.
Creating metastore index... mw_cirrus_metastore_first   Scanning available plugins...none
 ok
                Index is unknown retrying...^C
how to point to the index ?